# Best approach to waiting on pending live data using architecture components

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, apollo-android

I'm working on an application that fetches data from a graphql server via apollo-android.

I do a single fetch on my aws rds database. I do this fetch right at the `onCreate()` of my CalendarFragment.

The thing is, at `onViewCreated()`, I want to set my textview to one of the fields that is fetched, first and last name. So, I run my `getBarberFullName` method which returns the `String` value of `mBarberFullName`. I'm trying to follow the UI controller displays while the view model handles all the logic approach. `getBarberFullName` resides within my ViewModel.

```
    public String getBarberFullName() {
        if (appointmentsAreNull()) return mBarberFullName.getValue();
        AppointmentModel am = mMasterAppointments.getValue().get(0);
        String fullName = am.bFirstName;
        fullName = fullName.concat(" " + am.bLastName);
        // Get the logged in barber's full name and set it as mBarberFullName.
        mBarberFullName.setValue(fullName);
        return mBarberFullName.getValue();
    }
```

where `mMasterAppointments` is a `MutableLiveData<List<AppointmentModel>>`. In my `onViewCreated()` callback, I run

```
String barberName = mBarberViewModel.getBarberFullName();
        mTxtv_barberName.setText(barberName);
```

However, `mMasterAppointments` is always null so it just returns the default value of mBarberFullName which is a `String`.

However, if I were to run the following code, in the same `onViewCreated()`, I get the desired result where the textview is updated with the desired barber's full name.

```
  mBarberViewModel.getAllAppointments().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), am -> {
            if (am.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No barber.");
                return;
            }
            String barberGreeting;
            barberGreeting = am.get(0).bFirstName;
            barberGreeting = barberGreeting.concat(" " + am.get(0).bLastName);
            mTxtv_barberName.setText(barberGreeting);
        });
```

`getAllAppointments` returns an observer to `mMasterAppointments` located in my ViewModel.

Although `getAllAppointments` and `getBarberFullName` are called within `onViewCreated()`, one is able to access the pending values of `mMasterAppointments` while the other is not. Why?

I don't want to do the logic in my Fragments `onViewCreated` callback, so how can I wait on the pending `mMasterApointmentData` in my ViewModel's `getBarberFullName()`? Are there tools within `LiveData` and `ViewModel` that would aid me in this situation?

Comment: "Why?" -- because your observer is called when the network call completes. That network call is being done on a background thread. "so how can I wait on the pending mMasterApointmentData in my ViewModel's getBarberFullName()?" -- you don't. That would freeze your UI until your server responds, which might take some time. Users will be... unimpressed. Use `observe()`, as you are in the final code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LiveData's [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations) class

> when you need to perform calculations, display only a subset of the
> data, or change the rendition of the data.

First add a new String LiveData for `BarberFullName` in the viewmdoel, and give it the value of transforming (mapping) the source LiveData `mMasterAppointments` into the desired String:

```
val fullBarberName: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(mMasterAppointments) { am ->
         " ${am[0].bFirstName} ${am.get(0).bLastName}" 
}
```

Now you can observe this String LiveData in your fragment, the way you in did your second snippet.

Note that the code I provided is in Kotlin, I use it nowadays. I hope you get it.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.
I'm also looking to transition to Kotlin, got any good resources?